# Why list menu items not shown in SwiftUI project?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have list item menu project in SwiftUI, my project work, but I have list icons,  they are not shown in list view, even I was try to use system image, there is not any change on screen, any idea?

```
struct MasterView: View {

let  view1 =  Menu(name:"Home", image:"image_home", destination:.home)
let  view2 =  Menu(name:"View 1", image:"image_view1", destination:.view1)
let  view3 =  Menu(name:"View 3", image:"image_view2", destination:.view2)

var body: some View {
    let menus: [Menu] = [view1, view2, view3]

    return List {
        ForEach(menus) { menu in
            self.destinationView(menu: menu)
        }}}

func destinationView(menu: Menu) -> some View {
    
    switch menu.destination {
        case .view1:
            return NavigationLink(
                destination: AnyView(View1(menu: menu))
            )
            {
                Text("\(menu.name)")
            }
            
        case .view2:
               return NavigationLink(
                   destination: AnyView(View2(menu: menu))
               )
               {
                   Text("\(menu.name)")
               }
        default:
           return NavigationLink(
               destination: AnyView(HomeView(menu: menu))
           )
           {
               Text("\(menu.name)")
           }}}}
```

**Model.swift:**

```
/// Main menu item for the list
struct Menu: Identifiable {
var id = UUID()
var name: String
var image: String
var destination: ViewType
}

enum ViewType {
case home
case view1
case view2
}
```

Comment: your code is running fine on my side, I can see data populated within List.

Comment: @TusharSharma, how we can solve ?